# How to make two enums have the same keys?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have these two enums:

```
enum foo {
   bar,
   baz
}

enum fiz {
   ...
}
```

How can I make sure, that `fiz` has the same keys as `foo`? I tried adding an interface, but no luck with assigning.

Comment: Can you explain why do you need two enums to have the same keys?

Comment: I have labels and names for a form. I want the names and labels to have the same keys, but different values

Comment: I would not recommend using an `enum` for that - that's not the sort of use case they are for in TypeScript. An interface (with the keys) and multiple implementations sounds easier and more appropriate. Objects in TypeScript are very powerful in terms of what the type system lets you express.

Comment: Can you add it as an answer? I'm not sure I understand

Comment: I don't understand the question, enums don't have keys.

Comment: I also ran into the same problem as Alex, and I failed to understand why enum can't be used in Alex's usecase. Would anyone willing to share an example (as easy as possible) on how it is not suitable to use enums on form's `label` and `name` props ?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I'm trying to make a set of enums for country codes.  One will be the ISO-2 code, one will be the ISO-3 code, and one will be the numeric code.  The values are all different, but the keys would all be the same as it's all the same set of countries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70747879/how-to-make-two-enums-have-the-same-keys#comment125070940_70747879), I think this is approach will work well for you:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBA1gUwJ4RgXhgbQOQDMQjYA0M2ARgIYBOxplAXtgLowWqiRQDcAUFEgAcEMANLJ0MfkJC54yCJjABXALZkEVJlxgB6HTABE+EAZgAfQ5SqmLBhgZ59BwgPJkAVgmBQA6gEsoAAsAZQoVBDEUAB4ANQoAGyUEABVnAD4JACUvECoAEyjIkjjElPTeHg5oGHiKdXiIAC4YN09vfyDQ8MiIKOU1DQyMAG8eGBhjZoBGIjGYK2aAJlnxhmaAZlmAXwqq2DAwhCaWjy9fAJDDnqjoKj8wAHMhmFHxydJwBGI5hdIoAHdCCt5hR6M1sEEqAgvtsuEA)

```ts
const keys = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'] as const;
type Key = typeof keys[number]; // "foo" | "bar" | "baz"

type ObjectWithSameKeys<ValueType> = Record<Key, ValueType>;

const labels: ObjectWithSameKeys<number> = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2,
  baz: 3,
};

const names: ObjectWithSameKeys<string> = {
  foo: 'one',
  bar: 'two',
  baz: 'three',
};
```

Comment: Yeah, I think this makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a map.

```
enum foo {
  bar,
  baz,
}

const fiz = new Map<foo, string>([
  [foo.bar, 'value1'],
  [foo.baz, 'value2'],
]);
```

OR you can do something like this

```
enum Foo {
    A = "ActivityCode.Foo.A",
    B = "ActivityCode.Foo.B",
    C = "ActivityCode.Foo.C",
}

enum Bar {
    A = "ActivityCode.Bar.A",
    B = "ActivityCode.Bar.B",
    C = "ActivityCode.Bar.C",
}

enum Baz {
    A = "ActivityCode.Baz.A",
    B = "ActivityCode.Baz.B",
    C = "ActivityCode.Baz.C",
}

const ActivityCode = {
    Foo,
    Bar,
    Baz,
};

console.log(ActivityCode.Foo.A);
```

[reference](https://topherpedersen.blog/2021/06/07/nested-enums-in-typescript/)

Comment: This will create a const though, not an enum, right?

Comment: @AlexIronside yes, but a const is a better type for this use case than an enum. an Enum is an enumerated list of allowed values, and traditionally doesn't have key/value pairs. A Map is a great choice for storing key/value pairs, and making it const gives it the same type guarantees as an enum